# Get input from HTML and return result

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an app that calculates your weight on other celestial objects. The function does what it should when called with `weightConverter(object, weight);`.

But I can't seem to get the input from a HTML form.

How can I get the input from the HTML?
Also, is there a better way to getting the result back to the HTML?

```js
function weightConverter(){
  
      var object = document.getElementsByName('object');
      var weight = document.getElementsByName('weight');
  
      var objects = {
        Sun: 28,
        Mercury: 0.38,
        Venus: 0.91,
        Moon: 0.166,
        Mars: 0.38,
        Jupiter: 2.14,
        Saturn: 0.91,
        Uranus: 0.86,
        Neptune: 1.1,
        Pluto: 0.8
       }
  
       var result = weight*objects[object];
  
       document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML= object;
    }
```

```html
    <h2 id="calc">....</h2>

    <form>
      <p> Input weight in kilograms: </p>
      <input id="kilo" type="text" name="weight">

      <p>Choose object:</p>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Sun">Sun</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mercury">Mercury</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Venus">Venus</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Moon">Moon</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mars">Mars</label>     
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Jupiter">Jupiter</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Saturn">Saturn</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Uranus">Uranus</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Neptune">Neptune</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Pluto">Pluto</label> 
      


      <button onclick="weightConverter();" type="submit">Calculate!</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: use a dropdown instead and make sure to give your element's "id" as well. also, learn HTML

Comment: @zerohero Dropdown would certainly make more sense aesthetically and would be more user friendly. The `weight` input element has an identifier and the others don't need one. The radio buttons represent a group no need for an id on each of them, `name` works just fine and is all you need to get an array posted correctly in 
 a POST also `document.querySelector('input[name="object"]:checked')` works fine. - Generally I only add identifiers as well as other attributes if really needed not for the sake of it.

Comment: Okay cool, so throw HTML standards out the window then. That's fine I guess

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things you have to change. You need to get the `value` of the selected option not the object and you need to get the value for the weight not the element.

`var object = document.getElementsByName('object');` - This gets all options not just the selected option. You could loop through the results to see which one is `checked` but you could directly query for the selected, similar to this: `document.querySelector('input[name="object"]:checked');`

`var weight = document.getElementsByName('weight');` - This will get a collection as well but as you have an identifier on the element you can directly query for it an it's value, similar to: `document.getElementById('kilo').value;`

Other than that the rest was OK, except you tried to assign an `object` back to the text out put element which is now the proper value.

```js
function weightConverter(){      
      var selectedObjectValue = document.querySelector('input[name="object"]:checked').value;
      var weight = document.getElementById('kilo').value;
  
      var objects = {
        Sun: 28,
        Mercury: 0.38,
        Venus: 0.91,
        Moon: 0.166,
        Mars: 0.38,
        Jupiter: 2.14,
        Saturn: 0.91,
        Uranus: 0.86,
        Neptune: 1.1,
        Pluto: 0.8
       }
  
       var result = weight*objects[selectedObjectValue];
  
       document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML= result;
    }
```

```html
<h2 id="calc">....</h2>

    <form>
      <p> Input weight in kilograms: </p>
      <input id="kilo" type="text" name="weight">

      <p>Choose object:</p>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Sun" checked>Sun</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mercury">Mercury</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Venus">Venus</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Moon">Moon</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mars">Mars</label>     
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Jupiter">Jupiter</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Saturn">Saturn</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Uranus">Uranus</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Neptune">Neptune</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Pluto">Pluto</label> 
      


      <button onclick="weightConverter();" type="button">Calculate!</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate `document.getElementsByName('object')` to get the selected value and `document.getElementsByName('weight')[0].value` to get the value from input field.

```js
function weightConverter(){
  
      var object = document.getElementsByName('object');
      var weight = document.getElementsByName('weight')[0].value;
     var selectedObject = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
    if(object[i].checked){
        selectedObject = object[i].value;
    }
  }
  
      
      var objects = {
        Sun: 28,
        Mercury: 0.38,
        Venus: 0.91,
        Moon: 0.166,
        Mars: 0.38,
        Jupiter: 2.14,
        Saturn: 0.91,
        Uranus: 0.86,
        Neptune: 1.1,
        Pluto: 0.8
       }
  
       var result = weight*objects[selectedObject];
  
       document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML= result;
    }
```

```html
<h2 id="calc">....</h2>

      <p> Input weight in kilograms: </p>
      <input id="kilo" type="text" name="weight">

      <p>Choose object:</p>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Sun">Sun</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mercury">Mercury</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Venus">Venus</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Moon">Moon</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mars">Mars</label>     
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Jupiter">Jupiter</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Saturn">Saturn</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Uranus">Uranus</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Neptune">Neptune</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Pluto">Pluto</label> 
      


      <button onclick="weightConverter();" >Calculate!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have one input type text so it's better to use id instead of name
don't try make your code complicated

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
       function weightConverter(){
  
      var radios = document.getElementsByName('object');
 
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        var object=radios[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
      var weight = document.getElementById('kilo').value;
  
      var objects = {
        Sun: 28,
        Mercury: 0.38,
        Venus: 0.91,
        Moon: 0.166,
        Mars: 0.38,
        Jupiter: 2.14,
        Saturn: 0.91,
        Uranus: 0.86,
        Neptune: 1.1,
        Pluto: 0.8
       };
  
       var result = weight*objects[object];
       
  
       document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML= result;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h2 id="calc">....</h2>

    
      <p> Input weight in kilograms: </p>
      <input id="kilo" type="text" name="weight">

      <p>Choose object:</p>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Sun">Sun</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mercury">Mercury</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Venus">Venus</label>
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Moon">Moon</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mars">Mars</label>     
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Jupiter">Jupiter</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Saturn">Saturn</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Uranus">Uranus</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Neptune">Neptune</label> 
      <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Pluto">Pluto</label> 
      


      <button onclick="weightConverter();">Calculate!</button>
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove form tags and instead of submit button use a simple button and you should be in business. Try:

```
<h2 id="calc">....</h2>


  <p> Input weight in kilograms: </p>
  <input id="kilo" type="text" name="weight">

  <p>Choose object:</p>
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Sun">Sun</label>
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mercury">Mercury</label>
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Venus">Venus</label>
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Moon">Moon</label> 
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Mars">Mars</label>     
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Jupiter">Jupiter</label> 
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Saturn">Saturn</label> 
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Uranus">Uranus</label> 
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Neptune">Neptune</label> 
  <label><input name="object"type="radio" value="Pluto">Pluto</label> 



  <button onclick="weightConverter();" >Calculate!</button>
```

Comment: Oops Sorry!! Good catch there!!